# Código JavaScript não funciona

Tags: javascript

Estou trabalhando em uma página para a *web* e eu gostaria de saber por que o meu código não funciona. Simplesmente. Ele deve imprimir um "alert" caso as condições do *if* sejam verdadeiras mas isso não está acontecendo.

```js
//valida dados com javascript
function verifica(objeto) {

  // convertendo string para int
  objeto = parseInt(objeto);

  if ( objeto.value<1 )
  {
    alert("O número de empresas deve ser maior que 0.");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #C1CDC1;
}

p {
  color: #660066;
  font-size: x-large;
  font-family: Calibri;

}

.auto-style1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
</br> </br> </br>
<p class="auto-style1"> Um conjunto de empresas ligadas umas às outras forma uma rede de relacionamentos. </br>
Para medir o grau de conectividade da rede, use a calculadora abaixo:</p>
<!-- formulário -->
<form name="form" id="form" action="" method="get">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>Digite o número de empresas da rede.</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="txt_empresas" id="txt_empresas" value=""/> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Digite o número de conexões da rede.</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="txt_conexoes" id="txt_conexoes" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="button" name="btn_calcular" id="btn_calcular" value="Calcular"
                                            onsubmit="verifica(document.form.txt_empresas);" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

---

Eu fiz algumas alterações sugeridas aqui e ainda não consegui chegar ao resultado esperado. O 'alert' não aparece:

```js
//valida dados com javascript
function verifica(form1) {


  if ( (form1.txt_empresas.value == "") || (!isNum(form1.txt_empresas.value)) ||     (form1.txt_empresas.value <1) ) {
    alert ("Preencha o número de empresas corretamente.");
    form1.txt_empresas.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if ( (form1.txt_conexoes.value == "") || (!isNum(form1.txt_ligacoes.value)) || (form1.txt_conexoes.value <1) ) {
    alert ("Preencha o número de ligações corretamente.");
    form1.txt_conexoes.focus();
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

function isNum(v) {

  var ValidChars = "0123456789";
  var isNumber=true;
  var Char;

  for (i=0; i< v.length && isNumver ==true; i++) {

    Char = v.charAt(i);
    if (ValidChars.indexOf(Char) == -1) {

      IsNumber = false;
    }
  }
  return isNumber;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color:#CDC8B1;
}

p {
  color: #660066;
  font-size: x-large;
  font-family: Calibri;

}

.auto-style1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

form {
  align: center;
}
```

```html
<br/> <br/> <br/>
<p class="auto-style1"> Um conjunto de empresas ligadas umas às outras forma uma rede de relacionamentos. <br/>
  Para medir o grau de conectividade da rede, use a calculadora abaixo:</p>
<!-- formulário -->
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="processa.php" method="get" onsubmit="return    verifica(this);">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>Digite o número de empresas da rede.</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="txt_empresas" id="txt_empresas" value=""/> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Digite o número de conexões da rede.</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="txt_conexoes" id="txt_conexoes" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="btn_calcular" id="btn_calcular" value="Calcular" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Notei que faltou um `}` para encerrar a função `verifica`. Foi só um erro na hora de montar a pergunta, ou seu código está assim mesmo?

Comment: @Giannini, editei a sua pergunta para organizar o HTML, JS e CSS da mesma.

Answer (score 5):

O evento [onsubmit](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onsubmit.asp) não existe nos `inputs`. Ele é usado no form.

Coloque o evento no `form` e seu código funcionará.

Comment: Eu fiz algumas alterações sugeridas aqui e ainda não consegui chegar ao resultado esperado. O 'alert' não aparece. Veja a pergunta.

Comment: @Giannini Fiz um teste com o seu HTML, deixei os dois campos em branco e um `alert` apareceu. Você possui alguns erros de digitação, como "txt_ligacoes" ao invés de "txt_conexoes", "isNumver" ao invés de "isNumber" e "IsNumber" ao invés de "isNumber", mas corrija esses erros básicos que funcionará

Answer (score 4):

Boa noite.

Há algumas coisas a serem corrigidas no seu código.

1º -A função js esta errada o parseInt esta sendo executado no objeto e no valor e esta faltando fechar a ultima chave.

```
function verifica(objeto) {

            // convertendo string para int
            value = parseInt(objeto.value);
            if (value < 1)
            {
                alert("O número de empresas deve ser maior que 0.");
            }
        }
```

2º - O evento onsubmit deve estar no form e não no botão.

```
<form name="form" id="form" action="" method="get" onsubmit="verifica(document.form.txt_empresas);">
```

3º - O type do botão deve ser SUBMIT para recarregar o formulário.

```
<input type="submit" name="btn_calcular" id="btn_calcular" value="Calcular"/>
```

So uma observação, se eu fosse você começava a trabalhar com o id dos elementos, por exemplo ao invés de document.form.txt_empresas usar document.getElementById("txt_empresas")

Comment: Eu fiz algumas alterações sugeridas aqui e ainda não consegui chegar ao resultado esperado. O 'alert' não aparece. Veja a pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Duas coisas estavam erradas no seu código.

(TL;DR) Versão funcionando:
http://jsfiddle.net/su4rux5o/1/

Agora, sobre os erros:

1. Faltou converter o valor para número, antes de verificar se a quantidade era menor que 1 (form1.txt_empresas.value <1);
2. Na sua função isNum, você criou uma variável **isNumber**, porém no **for** você digitou **isNumver**.

Troquei também a forma como os inputs são acessados. Usando o getElementById e não a notação por pontos a partir do form.

Answer (score 0):

Giannini, existe uma implementação no ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) para verificar se o objeto do tipo Number é um Inteiro: [`Number.isInteger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger). Apesar dela não está disponivel em boa parte dos navegadores modernos, você pode usar uma adaptação do Polyfill sugerido no link.

Outro ponto, se quiser cancelar o envio do form, o ideal é chamar o `event.preventDefault()` ao invés de um `return false`.

```js
Number.prototype.isInteger = function() {
    return isFinite(this) && Math.floor(this) === this.valueOf();
};

var form1 = document.getElementById("form1");
form1.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
  var qtd = {};
  qtd.Empresas = parseInt(form1.txt_empresas.value);
  qtd.Conexoes = parseInt(form1.txt_conexoes.value);

  if (!qtd.Empresas.isInteger() || qtd.Empresas < 1) {
    
    alert ("Preencha o número de empresas corretamente.");
    form1.txt_empresas.focus();
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }

  if (!qtd.Conexoes.isInteger() || qtd.Conexoes < 1) {
    alert ("Preencha o número de ligações corretamente.");
    form1.txt_conexoes.focus();
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }

  return true;
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color:#CDC8B1;
}

p {
  color: #660066;
  font-size: x-large;
  font-family: Calibri;

}

.auto-style1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

form {
  align: center;
}
```

```html
<br/> <br/> <br/>
<p class="auto-style1"> Um conjunto de empresas ligadas umas às outras forma uma rede de relacionamentos. <br/>
  Para medir o grau de conectividade da rede, use a calculadora abaixo:</p>
<!-- formulário -->
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="processa.php" method="get">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>Digite o número de empresas da rede.</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="txt_empresas" id="txt_empresas" value=""/> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Digite o número de conexões da rede.</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="txt_conexoes" id="txt_conexoes" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="btn_calcular" id="btn_calcular" value="Calcular" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```